# Is the software center safe?

Tags: software-center, canonical, malware

Is there anyway someone could get some sort of malware onto the Ubuntu Software Center? Or is it all checked thoroughly before being added to the official repositories?

Comment: Sorry about that, but I just gave Toroidal this link as well. :)

Comment: Nah that's fine. I was hoping this would be flagged as a dupe - I was sure it would be here *somewhere*. I actually saw your convo and started looking for it too!